# Dockerize - Rails application curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-image

I have a ruby on rails application. It works on my mac machine. I want to dockerize it.

Docker file is below:

```
....
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server"]
```

I build the app and it works fine.

```
$docker build -t my-rails-app .
```

Docker image id

```
$docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
1f02e0e60da5        my-rails-app        "rails server"      5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   dazzling_hamilton
```

Get ip address

```
$docker inspect 1f02e0e60da5 | grep IPAddress
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
```

No response for http request
`$ curl 172.17.0.2:3000`

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 3000: Operation timed out
```

Comment: curl localhost:3000

Comment: Update Dockerfile CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]. "curl -X GET   http://localhost:3000" works.

Answer (score 0):

Update Dockerfile

```
...
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

run command:

```
curl -X GET   http://localhost:3000
```

It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Change your CMD for this one

```
CMD rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
```

You dont need to get the docker ip because it is being exposed on the localhost, so you can just do

`curl localhost:3000`

Comment: I have answered by question :) thnx

Answer (score 0):

The reason of you can't do `curl 172.17.0.2:3000`, Because this IP belongs to internal Docker network container. If you would have another container in the same Docker Network, then that should work. Curling your app container from different container (microservice structure).

Your container address `0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp`, You need to call localhost as i mentioned in comments. Docker network bridges yr container to network.